# RegEx replace returns unexpected result without .*

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, capture-group

I'm trying to create a regualr expression that does the following transformations:

1. `Apple Orange` > `AO`
2. `Load Module` > `LM`
3. `anApple Orange` > `O`
4. `toLoad Module` > `M`

I found a suitable pattern, but noticed a strange behavior. Here's my initial try:

```
/^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z])/
```

Running a replace on the third (and fourth) test case with this expression gives me a surprising result:

```
'anApple Orange'.replace(/^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z])/,'$1$2')
> "Orange"
```

Why is that surprising? Well, the first group obviously does not match, since the string does not start with a capital letter, but the second group only selects a **single** capital letter: `([A-Z])`, not everything after it: `([A-Z].*)`

To my surprise, adding `.*` right after the last capture group gave me the correct result:

```
'anApple Orange'.replace(/^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z]).*/,'$1$2')
> "O"
```

Why this is happening is beyond my understanding of JS and Regular Expressions. I'm thrilled to know what sort of dark magic is causing a singe `[A-Z]` to return multiple, and even some lowercase chracters.

Here's a runnable demo:

```js
var testCases = [
      'Apple Orange',
      'Load Module',
      'anApple Orange',
      'toLoad Module'
    ],
    badregex = /^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z])/,
    goodregex = /^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z]).*/;

document.onreadystatechange = function(n){
  if (document.readyState === "complete"){
      for (var i=0,l=testCases.length; i<l; i++){
        var p = document.createElement('p'),
            testCase = testCases[i];
        p.innerHTML = ""+testCase+" &gt; "+testCase.replace(badregex,'$1$2')
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
      for (var i=0,l=testCases.length; i<l; i++){
        var p = document.createElement('p'),
            testCase = testCases[i];
        p.innerHTML = ""+testCase+" &gt; "+testCase.replace(goodregex,'$1$2')
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do like,

```
> "Apple Orange".replace(/(?:^|\s)([A-Z])|./g, "$1")
'AO'
```

Don't complex the things. Just capture all the uppercase chars which exists just after to a space or at the start. And then match all the remaining characters. Now replace all the matched chars by `$1`. Note that all the matched characters are replaced with the chars present inside the replacement part.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rV0iE9/2)

Why?

```
'anApple Orange'.replace(/^([A-Z])?[^ ]* ([A-Z])/,'$1$2')
> "Orange"
```

- `([A-Z])?` checks for an optional uppercase letter at the start. There is no such thing. So it captures an empty string.
- `[^ ]*` matches zero or more non-space characters.
- `<space>` matches a space.
- `([A-Z])` captures only the first letter in Orange.
- Now by replacing all the matched chars with `$1` -> empty string `$2` -> `O` will give you `Orange`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just to make sure : The `|` in `(?:^|\s)` is only for `^` vs `\s` right ? the non capture group is not relates to the _left side_ of the pipe....right ?

Comment: `(^|\s)` will capture a space or start of the line boundary. `(?:^|\s)` will match space or start of the line boundary. We use a group here instead of a character class like `[^\s]` or `[\s^]` because `^` inside a char class will loose it's special meaning of matching start of the line boundary.

Comment: I meant : it's not `?:^` vs `\s` , I mean , the non captured group doesnt belong to the OR operation.right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, the 2 characters just mean it's a group that should not be captured.

Comment: yep, you're right.. It's just a group or container which holds `^` and `\s`

Answer (score 1):

Your first example matches `anApple O`. The `$1` is empty because `^([A-Z])?`  is optional and does not match and `$2` is `O`  so you replace `anApple O`  by `O` in the string `anApple Orange` and this will result in `Orange`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I somehow mixed up matching and replacing. Still, I'm going to accept Avian's answer, because of the addition of a cleaner method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `replace` with a complex regex you can use a a very simple regex with `match` and use `join` to get your desired output:

```
'anApple Orange'.match(/\b([A-Z])/g).join('')
//=> O

'Apple Orange'.match(/\b([A-Z])/g).join('')
//=> AO
```

Comment: This is also a great solution, the only issue with it for me is that I actually want to use the regular expression in PHP rather than JS, and a single replace is easier to do there than matching & joining. This is obviously not your fault as I did not mention this anywhere, and it'd be a perfect solution if I was going for a strict JS-specific approach

Comment: Even in PHP it can be done easily using `implode` function. I will update in a min.

Comment: You shouldn't edit PHP code into the answer as the question is for JS. I could write the PHP code myself, I'm just saying that a replace is more suitable for me across languages. Also, `implode` is the commonly used name of the `join` function, it's just an alias.

Comment: Yes probably but comparing regex used in `replace` and `match`, I think I would choose the simpler option.